# How can I turn binding errors into runtime exceptions?

Tags: wpf, debugging, exception, data-binding

Just as there is "treat warning as errors" set in our projects to catch early possible problems, I would love to have a runtime exception to catch them early.

I have recently been bit by this problem and I would have been glad to have this.

Can it be done? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could hook into the [`PresentationTraceSources`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources(v=vs.110).aspx) collection with your own listener:

```
public class BindingErrorListener : TraceListener
{
    private Action<string> logAction;
    public static void Listen(Action<string> logAction)
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners
            .Add(new BindingErrorListener() { logAction = logAction });
    }
    public override void Write(string message) { }
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        logAction(message);
    }
}
```

and then hook it up in code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        BindingErrorListener.Listen(m => MessageBox.Show(m));
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new string[] { "hello" };
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML with a binding error

```
    <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BadBinding}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does this work only when I run my application within visual studio? How about when I publish my application to a share and run the wpf exe from there?

Answer (score 14):

I implemented a solution very similar to the one proposed by Dean Chalk:

1. Derived a `TraceListener` that throws instead of logging
2. Added that listener to `PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource`

Please see the [complete solution on GitHub](https://github.com/bblanchon/WpfBindingErrors), it includes a demo application and a unit test project.

[image: Exception in Visual Studio]

Comment: Cool. You could turn it into NuGet package.

Comment: Readers may find it useful to look at this additional information on an answer to a different question, where Benoit has also posted *this* answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641847/5198140

Comment: And I've just noticed that Benoit seems to have taken Robert's advice, and put this in a NuGet package, thanks Benoit... https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfBindingErrors/

Answer (score 0):

First add this class to your project:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfTestApp
{
    public class BindingErrorListener : TraceListener
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(new BindingErrorListener());
        }

        public override void Write(string message)
        {
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
#if DEBUG
            throw new System.Exception(message);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the Register method in your App.xaml.cs class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        BindingErrorListener.Register();
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way, (by throwing an exception) if you have any binding errors then **you will be aware of those errors in the first place**, that is, as soon as you start (F5) your application. If you wish, you can log those by injecting your logger object in the `BindingErrorListener` constructor.