# Display custom width tooltip in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am displaying a tooltip in a WPF DataGrid but I want to customize the width of it so it is no larger then the size of the cell containing the data.  I tried setting the Path to "Width" and "ActualWidth" but it ignores them both.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Message" Width="*">
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="60000" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                            Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this which helps explain why it isn't working,

[How can I turn binding errors into runtime exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225867/how-can-i-turn-binding-errors-into-runtime-exceptions)

So you add this,

```
public class BindingErrorListener : TraceListener
{
    private Action<string> logAction;
    public static void Listen(Action<string> logAction)
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners
            .Add(new BindingErrorListener() { logAction = logAction });
    }
    public override void Write(string message) { }
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        logAction(message);
    }
}
```

And add this to your code behind,

```
BindingErrorListener.Listen(m => MessageBox.Show(m));
InitializeComponent();
```

So basically the result of that is your code has a binding error in it,

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
```

The binding error occurs before you hover over the DataGridTextColumn, so I am wondering if the binding is being created before the TextBox is being added to the visual tree, so it doesn't have an ancestor etc.

So far this tells you why the problem exists, but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: This in itself is helpful for finding future exceptions as well.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I tried a number of things (probably about 6 or 8 different things) to set the width which is the main problem you are trying to solve, but I found nothing that worked.

Comment: Thanks for your work Peter.  Guess I will have to find an alternative.  Maybe I will forgo the usage of the tooltip and roll my own, or just live with the very long tooltip.