# Binding - disable break on property throw

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, exception, binding

Using exception validation

```
<TextBox>
    <Binding Path="Value"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ExceptionValidationRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

for this property

```
int _value = 1;
public int Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        _value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

If I enter nonsense (e.g. `1asdkfjlsdf`) `TextBox` will get a red border. Fine.

But as soon as I enter `0` while debugging break will occurs

[image]

and I have to click <kbd>Continue</kbd> on debugging bar every time.

Without debugging it work as expected: red border for either `12093813asdf` or `0` value.

Question: how do I prevent that break?

I can un-check specific exception (arrow on screenshot), but I want breaks when this exception occurs in other places (e.g. in Model logic `ArgumentException` is thrown in some methods too). I can make my own exception, throw it and un-check it, but I am not happy with that either.

Comment: I'm confused.  You're telling it to throw an exception, but then getting upset when it throws the exception?  I think you may be intending to use ValidationResults.  Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753962%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Khale_Kitha, point is random input (e.g. `0983abcd`) is catch by binding, while `0` goes to property and then it's sudden unhandled exception. Haven't thought about custom validation rule, thanks. Though I have no idea how to make own `ExceptionBinding`, will I be able to catch property thrown exception myself? Do you want to save me some time by showing how to do it?

Comment: I had too much to put here.  Will attempt to post an answer that may help.

Answer (score 1):

The random input is caught by your `ExceptionValidationRule` because `0983abcd` is not an integer. (More on that, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.exceptionvalidationrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When you send random nonsense, it's failing the string->int conversion and triggering the `ExceptionValidationRule` to color your box.  However, when you send the 0, it's triggering *your* exception, which is not inside a try/catch (unhandled), and then pushes to the validationrule which notices the previous exception and sets the box to red.

Check the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753962%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), from my comment, for a great example on how to do a second validationrule to check for your `< 1` condition.  (You can replace `ExceptionvalidationRule` entirely with it, as well.)

Check out the answer, [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882062/binding-integer-in-xaml-does-not-result-in-error), as to why your failures, outside of debugging, do not cause a crash.  It is designed to fail, gracefully, in order to prevent simple binding issues from causing more trouble.  You're still getting the error, but it's just being hidden from you.