# Do not break during debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, exception, mvvm

This question seems very similar to [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35484679/1997232), but the case is a bit different (perhaps better demonstrating the problem), though goal is the same.

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:ExceptionBinding Path=Color1}" />
```

cs:

```
public class ExceptionBinding : Binding
{
    public ExceptionBinding()
    {
        ValidationRules.Add(new ExceptionValidationRule());
    }
}
```

vm:

```
    Color _color1;
    public string Color1
    {
        get { return (new ColorConverter()).ConvertToString(_color1); }
        set { _color1 = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(value); }
    }
```

When this code runs standalone, for input *`123`* red border is shown around `TextBox` (field value is not changing). Entering *`red`* or *`#FF0000`* will remove border and update field value.

Problem: when running program under Visual Studio, entering *`123`* will throw at `ConvertFromString` ([undocumented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533(v=vs.110).aspx) btw):

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Token is not valid.

**How to prevent Visual Studio from interrupting program execution?**

Comment: if you are getting an exception in visual studio, so are your users. if you want to continue to program execution, just hit F5 (or the  green arrow play button on VS) to continue to program execution.

Comment: @user1666620, it's not the bug, I'd like to avoid execution being interrupted.

Comment: i've updated my comment as you responded.

Comment: can you just handle the exception so its not a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Visual Studio ignore exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688574/make-visual-studio-ignore-exceptions)

Comment: @Jacobr365, if I handle it, then the whole purpose of validation with `ExceptionValidationRule` is killed (there will be no red border anymore).

Comment: @user1666620, I can't ignore `FormatException` as it can be thrown in other places of the program and I may need to debug those. It's rather uncomfortable to disable/enable it like this.

Comment: In the catch block just paint a red outline.

Comment: @Sinatr if you don't want to ignore exceptions, just continue the program execution by hitting F5 to continue the program.

Comment: @user1666620, once, second time, third time, ... , 100500 time? There are several places where I am currently using `ExceptionValidationRule`, it gets uncomfortable. This is why I am here.

Comment: @Sinatr do i have to become your google searcher? https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=visual+studio+ignore+specific+exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518080/how-to-force-visual-studio-debugger-to-skip-specific-exceptions

Comment: @user1666620, I don't want to skip specific exception. What I **would like** is some kind of property attribute... or rather compiler directive which tells to VS something like "please, when running this method in VS, ignore `BlablablaException`". That would be perfect, because I can apply it locally without having *side-effect* and necessity to manage exceptions (which seems I am currently trying to avoid).

Answer (score 3):

You can choose on what exception Visual Studio break by pressing '<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>'
or hit "Debug" Menu, Windows and Exception Settings
(see MSDN for more infos : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)

Thent uncheck the exceptions you don't want to see (for converters, just uncheck CLR exceptions)

After that, just pay attention to the Output Window for that kind of exceptions...