# Capture WPF binding errors programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application and would like to capture and log WPF binding errors to the application's logging system.  So far, the best I've been able to find when it comes to logging binding errors (or debug information in general) from WPF [involves adding an entry to the app.config](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486#.VnQ7LEorKUk) file.

I realize I could accomplish this by adding my own listener type to the app config as outlined in the link above, but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible, which leads to my question:

How can I programmatically add a trace listener to capture the WPF trace output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225867/how-can-i-turn-binding-errors-into-runtime-exceptions may have an answer already.

Comment: @Joey Excellent, `PresentationTraceSources` was what I was looking for.